# 2001 2nd gen Ram 1500 steering is really loose and tightens up under braking

Tags: dodge, steering, ram

I have a 2001 Dodge Ram 1500 and the steering is really loose. I can turn the steering wheel almost half the way around before it actually starts to turn. And when I step on the brakes the steering tightens right up and feels like the power steering went. If someone can help me figure out what’s going on that’d be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a serious problem somewhere in your front suspension. Normally the steering is very loose because you have one or more worn out suspension components, that move out of place under the load of braking and make steering very difficult. Your power steering is probably fine, but the dislocation of the components make steering mechanically difficult. It is impossible to say which exact component causes this behavior, but i'd suggest to see a qualified mechanic right away and not to drive around with this as it sounds very unsafe te me.